# ODBC driver can't read user data in SQL server authentication mode

Tags: sql-server, odbc, unixodbc

A have a problem to make ODBC connection from ORACLE database to MS SQL Server.

I’ve already achieved to connect with sqlcmd. So the servers see each others and can communicate.
The ODBC driver fails at the authentication, because it can’t read the user and password data from the odbc.ini file.
I read that this happens because the odbc driver does not accept the authentication data if it’s stored in plain text, but there were no explanation how can I store data in an other way.

Environment:

- ODBC driver: Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server
- Driver manager: Unix ODBC 2.3.0
- OS: ORACLE linux 6.5
- Target database: MS SQL Server 2008 R2

This works:

```
sqlcmd -S address -U username -P password
```

odbc.ini file:

```
[SQL_LINK]
Driver = ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server
Server = tcp:address,port
UID = username
PWD = password
```

Log file:

```
[ODBC][913][1417453346.612341][SQLConnect.c][3654]
                Entry:
                        Connection = 0x18f40a0
                        Server Name = [SQL_LINK][length = 8 (SQL_NTS)]
                        User Name = [NULL]
                        Authentication = [NULL]
                UNICODE Using encoding ASCII 'UTF8' and UNICODE 'UTF16LE'

                DIAG [28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user ''.
```

Answer (score 1):

Other than using a ODBC driver that does read uid/pwd from the ini all you can do is get the app to pass in the details. You don't mention what application is calling the driver?

Comment: I use the 'isql SQL_LINK' command to test the link. How do you think to manage the app which pass the user details?

Comment: If you are using isql, then "isql SQL_LINK uid pwd" will do what you want

Comment: I use the isql command only for test purposes. The final aim is to create a working db link in oracle.

Answer (score 1):

ODBC configuration can specify if you use SQL autentication or integrated. But you cannot use it to store user and password. This is true in windows. Not so sure unser linux, but an ODBC is an ODBC.

I don't know application or technology you are useing, but: **you need to populate the appropriate connection string with user and password**.

Just a suggestion for connection strings: http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Comment: The Postgre ODBC driver can store user data in the odbc.ini file, I thought that it's usualy working. In ORACLE SQL developer I made a db link `CREATE PUBLIC DATABASE LINK SQL_LINK CONNECT TO "un" IDENTIFIED BY "pw" USING 'SQL_LINK';` but when I run a select it says `ORA-28545: error diagnosed by Net8 when connecting to an agent
Unable to retrieve text of NETWORK/NCR message 65535`